# dialogflow projects.agent.intents.get doesn't work

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I try testing the rest api v2 and "try this api" doesn't work

the name parat is projects//agent/intents/test2Intent

I got the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'test2Intent' is not a valid intent ID. Must be a UUID.\ncom.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: \u003ceye3 title='INVALID_ARGUMENT'/\u003e generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: 'test2Intent' is not a valid intent ID. Must be a UUID.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

It looks like test2Intent isn't correct. Where is find the intent id? test2Intent is a name of intent and I can't find the intent id